# Normalize JSON data

Tags: json, jq

Given the following JSON structure

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "000000000014444A",
            "teams": [
                "000000000011AE74"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "000000000014434B",
            "teams": [
                "000000000011AE74",
                "00000000001583CE",
                "000000000010B4D7"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I use jq to structure the data as

```
[
    {
        "id": "000000000014444A",
        "team": "000000000011AE74"
    },
    {
        "id": "000000000014434B",
        "team": "000000000011AE74"
    },
    {
        "id": "000000000014434B",
        "team": "00000000001583CE"
    },
    {
        "id": "000000000014434B",
        "team": "000000000010B4D7"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take the `.data` array, and `map` each item to an object. Use `.teams[]` to iterate without capturing the items in a separate array, so the output is multiplicated:

```bash
jq '.data | map({id, team: .teams[]})'
```

```json
[
  {
    "id": "000000000014444A",
    "team": "000000000011AE74"
  },
  {
    "id": "000000000014434B",
    "team": "000000000011AE74"
  },
  {
    "id": "000000000014434B",
    "team": "00000000001583CE"
  },
  {
    "id": "000000000014434B",
    "team": "000000000010B4D7"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/UruZrvGZljS)

Answer (score 3):

There are a several ways to get the result that you want. One of them is described in [@pmf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77160253/4265352).

This is another way:

```bash
jq '[ .data[] | { id, team: .teams[] } ]'
```

How it works:

1. `.data` extracts the property `data` from the input (the input is an object); the value of property `data` is an array;
2. `[]` splits the array into items; the output of `.data[]` consists of multiple values, each value is one of the items of `.data`; the output of `.data[]` consists of two objects;
3. `|` - the next filters apply to each input value independent of other values; the input values are the values produced by `.data[]`;
4. `{ id, team: .teams[] }` - the output of this filter is an object (`{ ... }`) whose properties are `id` and `team`;

   - `id` is a shorthand of `id: .id`; the key (`id`) is the name of the property in the output object; the value (`.id`) is a filter that extracts the property `id` of each input object (the input objects have the properties `id` and `teams`);
   - `team: .teams[]` produce the property `team` in the output object; its value is the value of property `teams` from the input object; `teams` is an array in the input object but `[]` after `.team` split the value of `teams` into individual items; the expression `.teams[]` produce multiple output values from one input value; it produces one result for the object with `id` equal to `"000000000014444A"` and three results for the object with `id` equal to `"000000000014434B"`.

   All in all, the expression `.data[] | { id, team: .teams[] }` produce four results as output.
5. The outer `[` and `]` wrap the results produced by the enclosed pipeline into an array. The array (which is the output of the entire program) contains the four items generated by the inner expression. It is the output that you expect.

See it on the [jq playground](https://jqplay.org/s/05w0UiCeUZZ).

Comment: Amazing explanation - thank you for teaching me to fish !

Comment: Both answers were very helpful but I accepted the first one - I very much appreciate your answer though.

Comment: yeah, `map( ... )` is equivalent to `[ .[] | ... ]`. But thats' the point. It makes it more readable.